# limit size of chat log

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, chat

I'm folowing this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/) to create php/jquery based chat application.

In short, this code puts message to log:

```
<?  
session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){  
    $text = $_POST['text'];  

    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');  
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").") <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");  
    fclose($fp);  
}  
?>
```

And this line of code displays log

```
function loadLog(){       

        $.ajax({  
            url: "log.html",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div  
            },  
        });  
    }
```

`Log` is just simple HTML document.

How could I limit log to display only last 100 messages? And that log doesn't get too big? ( over 1 MB )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be what you want:

```
$lines = file('log.html');

// get line number 2 - 100
if(count($lines) > 100) $lines = array_slice(1, 99);

// convert newlines to <br/> and append
$lines[] = 
   nl2br("<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").") <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");

file_put_contents('log.html', join("\n", $lines));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that way (Probably there will be one better solution)

```
function loadLog(){       

    $.ajax({  
        url: "log.html",  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(html){  
            $("#chatbox").filter(function (index) {
              return index < 100;
            }).html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div  
        },  
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to limit the log to only contain 100 messages or only to display 100 and cut if filesize reaches threshold?(1MB)
(I wonder what you do with 100+messages when you only display 100?)

But when adding a new message, you could check if there are already 100 messages in the log and (if true) drop the first(oldest) message and append the newest msg?

Since you don't know the length of the messages, you need to read the whole filecontent and count the messages manually (e.g. by counting the substr 'div class=\'msgln\'') and completely rewrite (means mode 'w') the log.